# publish artifact from someone else to maven central

Tags: java, maven

I use the open-source [warcbase library](https://github.com/lintool/warcbase) (org.warcbase:warcbase:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT) in a project. However, the library is not published in a maven repository yet (neither a release nor a snapshot) (some people asked them to do so, but they didn't do it for some reason).

So, what is the proper way to publish it to maven central?

Solution 1: I build the snapshot, and I publish it to maven central (in their name).

Solution 2: I fork the project on github, I change version from `0.1.0-SNAPSHOT` to `0.1.0a`, I change the group name from `org.warcbase` to `com.github.dportabella`, and then I publish it to maven central.

Solution 3: ??

Comment: I'd go for solution3: setup a nexus server and put it there ( http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/ )

Comment: I second solution 3. You do not want to go publicly publishing someone else's work, anywhere. The reason why it is not in Maven central yet might have something to do with that 0.1.0-SNAPSHOT version, which reads like "this project is nowhere near ready for release".

Comment: I'd prefer to make it publicly available, as it is useful to other people also. And I would prefer not to install and maintain a repository software.

Comment: @Gimby, developers understand that 0.1.0 (instead of 1.0) is not a "near ready for release", so it's ok to publish it with such a version. Another option for the authors would be to publish it as snapshot. About publishing someone else's work, it is an open-source project with a license stating that anybody can fork it.

Comment: my understanding of version "0.1.0" is: only little features, but stable. "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT" means the same, but also buggy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [Nexus OSS](https://www.sonatype.com/download-oss-sonatype) version 2.11.3. It's free and it works absolute reliable.

If you're working with maven, it's recommended to use version 2.x (see [Nexus-Repository-Manager-3-0-0-Release-Notes](https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/217965118-Nexus-Repository-Manager-3-0-0-Release-Notes).

If you want to host the warcbase library, publish it to the "3rd party libraries" repository within this "personal" nexus.

Comment: I'd prefer to make it publicly available, as it is useful to other people also. And I would prefer not to install and maintain a repository software.